# How to stop people accessing this page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code which allows me to post a message to the currently logged in users facebook wall:

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    session_start();

    require("facebook.php");

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'app_id_here',
        'secret' => 'secret_here',
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    if( !empty( $session ) ) {

        try {

            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $user = $facebook->api('/me');

            $api_call = array( 
                'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission', 
                'uid' => $uid, 
                'ext_perm' => 'publish_stream' 
            ); 

            $can_post = $facebook->api($api_call); 

            if( $can_post ) { 

                $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', array('message' => 'post some message here')); 
                echo 'Posted! Then redirect to an appropriate page.'; 

            } else { 

                $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
                    'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'  
                ));  

                header("Location: {$url}");  
                exit;

            } 

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            echo $e;
            exit;

        }

    } else {

        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
            'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'  
        ));

        header("Location: {$url}");

    }
?>
```

I need to use this code in multiple places on my site, and need to constantly change the message being posted.  So I thought I should use the url query string to send the message to the code above.  i.e.

header("Location: post_message.php?message=" . $some_message_here);

But that would mean that anyone who figures out the url will be able to start posting random messages right? i.e.

http://mysite.com/post_message.php?message=some message here

How do I use the code above in all the pages I need, pass it a string for the message to be posted, but stop users navigating to the page to post random messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Put the file outside your webroot
2. Wrap the code in a function
3. Where you want to use it, [include](http://php.net/include) it and call the function.

Comment: I have wrapped it in a function and placed it in `/var/functions/post_facebook_message.php`.  The file which is accessing it is located at `/var/www/folder1/post_message.php` and I am not sure how to include the `post_facebook_message.php` in the `post_message.php` file?  I've tried `include("../../functions/post_facebook_message.php")`

Comment: `include('/var/functions/post_facebook_message.php');`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.  So that is an absolute path.  How do you use relative paths?

Comment: Same as normal. `../` for up a level and so on.

Comment: I was trying `include("../../functions/post_facebook_message.php")`, should it have been `include("../functions/post_facebook_message.php")`

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario the logged in user would be able to post any message to their wall from your application.  If the messages are not user generated to begin with then I do not see why it would not be a finite number of messages.

I would suggest that you define your messages and pass an identifier to that message.  If the message is to have variable content you can pass that as well.  I would define a message object with all expected parameters including a unique identifier token and JSON encode it and pass it as the only variable in the get request.